# cannot run Py_Initialize(), application exited with code -1073741191

Tags: python, c, embedding, cpython

I'm currently testing around with embedding Python in a C application, however I couldn't get it to work at all. I can build it just fine, but running it returns no error, only the Application error with the exit status of -1073741191.

Here's my code:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef _DEBUG
#include <C:\Users\name\anaconda3\include\Python.h>
#define _DEBUG
#else
#include <C:\Users\name\anaconda3\include\Python.h>
#endif
int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("dummy");
    Py_Initialize();
    Py_Finalize();

  
    return 0;
}
```

And in the linker, additional library directories: I put a path to python38.lib. I searched online and the exit code status has no meaning, and there's nothing that indicates what go wrong, only the application error after the apparent successful build.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I just haven't included the python .dll file inside my project